# File write with [NSBundle mainBundle] fails

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, file-io

I am trying to take content from one file and write it into another. I am reading fine, but I am not able to write it into another file.

I have a database of words. I want to separate the words into different files based on the number of letters. All four letter words go into one file, and so on. I added a txt file called "4letter" into my resources and the following is my code:

```
NSError *error;

//READ
NSString *dbFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"words" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *test = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:dbFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

//convert from string to array
NSArray *lines = [test componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]; 

NSFileHandle *logFile = nil;
logFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"4letter" ofType:@"txt"]];

//Test if write works
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) 
{
    NSString *randomAnagram = [[lines objectAtIndex:i] lowercaseString];
    [logFile writeData: [randomAnagram dataUsingEncoding: NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding]];
}
```

Answer (score 26):

In iOS, you can't write into a file in your app's bundle -- the entire bundle is read-only. Use a path into the Documents folder instead.

Comment: What is the path to the documents folder? My target is the iOS. After writing into it where can I find the folder?

Comment: See [Standard System Directories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LowLevelFileMgmt/Articles/StandardDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001279-SW4) to learn how to locate the Documents directory, as well as other standard directories.

Comment: To get a path to the documents folder use:
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentsDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: Even if you could write to the bundle, the bundle is not backed up and your app's data would be lost.

Comment: Is it document folder is secure for my data. I want same security like  app bundle with edit facility. Is it possible?

Comment: @python Please start your own question where you can be more specific about what you want. A large part of the "security" of the app bundle comes from the fact that it's not writeable, so a folder that *is* writeable obviously lacks that.

Comment: @Caleb I just want others cant get my imp data easily or need security for my file will be secure no one can use that data in other app.

Comment: @python So why not create a question and ask that? It's not the same as this question, and in any case the answer probably requires more space than a comment allows. With that in mind, it'd be great if you could delete your previous comments here -- reduce the clutter. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

See special [File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for better understnading.
In iOS, you can't write into a file in your app's bundle -- the entire bundle is read-only.

Consider reading [iOS Data Storage Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html) to better understand the purpose of directories below, in context of iCloud backup.

**<Application_Home>/AppName.app**

> This is the bundle directory containing the app itself. Do not write
>   anything to this directory. To prevent tampering, the bundle directory
>   is signed at installation time. Writing to this directory changes the
>   signature and prevents your app from launching again.

---

**<Application_Home>/Documents/**

> Use this directory to store critical user documents and app data
>   files. Critical data is any data that cannot be recreated by your app,
>   such as user-generated content. The contents of this directory can be
>   made available to the user through file sharing. The contents of this
>   directory are backed up by iTunes.

---

**<Application_Home>/Library/**

> This directory is the top-level directory for files that are not user
>   data files. You typically put files in one of several standard
>   subdirectories but you can also create custom subdirectories for files
>   you want backed up but not exposed to the user. You should not use
>   this directory for user data files. The contents of this directory
>   (with the exception of the Caches subdirectory) are backed up by
>   iTunes. For additional information about the Library directory, see
>   “The Library Directory Stores App-Specific Files.”

See full list (tmp/, Documents/Inbox) in [iOS Standard Directories: Where Files Reside](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW4)

**UPDATE** 
I use NSFileManager method `URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:`

Comment: I read this full document even. I have confusion, if i have save my very imp file or videos in document folder. Then it will available to others easily.

Comment: You can't share files like this because every file is visible only from your app. To share docs you need [`Document Interaction Programming Guide`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403)

Answer (score 8):

Like Caleb said, you can't write to your app's directory, but you can write to your app's Documents folder. You can get it like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

Answer (score 6):

Your app's bundle is read-only. There is two ways I could see:

1) Write in documents folder:

```
NSArray *pathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path =  [myPathList  objectAtIndex:0];
```

2) Use sqlite database. This is the same as 1 (you must save db in documents anyway), but you're using sqlite database. I think this is better than a lot of txt and plist files: [here's a tutorial on the topic](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/).

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"set.txt"];

NSString *data=@"Kostas";

[data writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];   

NSString *myData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:appFile];   

NSLog(@"Data : %@ ",myData);
```

Comment: What does this do differently from the code in the question? Why does  the code in the question fail, and how does your code avoid that problem?

Comment: The differently is that I locate my file to Documents directory of the application, where I have access to write it. The code in the question uses app's bundle which is read-only.